# How do I open another Python file within a file with a parameter/argument/variable attached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables

I want to run another file from my main.py and also set the value of a variable in the main.py and "export it", so I can use it in the other file.
But I absolutely don´t know how to do that.
So that I can set a 'var = x[3]' in the main file and kinda "export" the variable into the file that I am opening like 'import otherfile.py(var = x[3])'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail, what you are doing and provide a short example of the code (of main and second scripts). Right now it seems that you just need to pass your variable to the imported function from the second script

Comment: This is not normal usage. Unless you have very unusual requirements, just make use of Python's core feature: [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), and pass the value as an argument to wherever it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To import any variable from main file to otherfile you can use,

```
from main import*
Y = var
```

That's how you can set var in main.py file and import or use it in otherfile.py.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sys.argv` to get arguments if you run the file from the command line
so if you have the file:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

then open a command line and type `python file.py hello` it will print 'hello'.

As well, you can use `os.system()` to run command line functions from python
so your first file could be:

```
import os
var = 'test'
os.system(f"python otherfile.py {var}")
```

and otherfile.py could be:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

then if you run the first file, a python window will open and print 'test'.
Hope this was what you were looking for